# Combine DataFrames in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I have a vendor giving me multiple zipped data file on an S3 bucket which I need to read all together for analysis using Pyspark. How do I modify the sc.textFile() command?

Also, if I am loading 10 files, how do I reference them? Or are they all going into a single RDD?

On a broader level, how would I tweak the partitions, memory on an AMAZON EMR cluster? Each zipped file is 3MB in size or 1.3GB unzipped.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have a script which will move all the unzip files into a directory and then as part of yur spark code you can refer to that directory

```
rdd = sc.textFile(("s3://path/to/data/")
```

As you mentioed it's 1.3 GB data which is not huge for spark to process, you can leave to spark to have required partitions, however you can define them while creating rdd.

For Amazon EMR, you can spin smaller nodes based on the type of reuirement
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-supported-instance-types.html

Based on kind of processing(memory intensive/ compute intensive), choose machine type.

**HTH**